# Coordinates appearing off coast of Ireland regardless of projection set

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, csv

I have a CSV dataset containing XYZ information in which I've imported into QGIS.

Edit: Imported via following process.

1. Open Data Source Manager --> Add Delimited Text
2. Open CSV and select X, Y and Z fields --> Set EPSG as 4326 --> Click OK
3. Change Project Properties to EPSG:29902

The points should be located in Northern Ireland, however they're appearing off the coast of Ireland. See below
[image]

I've tried projecting to EPSG:2157, EPSG:29902 and EPSG:29903- all of which produce this.

My data looks like this for reference, but what am I doing wrong?

```
54.426758   -6.4405994  1.738
54.42676    -6.440602   1.769
54.426765   -6.4406033  1.78
54.42677    -6.4406047  1.821
```

Comment: when you say you are projecting the data, what are you doing? The data are clearly in lat lon and should be imported as such.

Answer (score 8):

EPSG:2157, EPSG:29902 and EPSG:29903 all have coordinates in meters but your data seems to be in Latitude, Longitude. Try importing them with EPSG4326 and then setting project projection to the one you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just tried that but they still seem to be appearing off the coast of Ireland. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are trying to reproject the data using layer properties, source and then setting the CRS to one of the above mentioned. The CRS for that layer should be set to EPSG:4326 / WGS84 and then you project your entire map to whatever projection you want using Project - Properties and set the CRS.

You can open any number of data sets in different projections in QGIS, then they all will be projected to the project CRS, but for this to work, QGIS must know what are the source projections of the data sets.

Setting the CRS for the layer to your intended projection will just lie to QGIS what the projection of the layer is and the data will then end up 54.42... meters north of and 6.44 meters west of the origin of the projection.

Don't be ashamed, it is a very typical beginners mistake in QGIS.

Comment: I have imported the CSV as EPSG:4326 and then set the projects projection to EPSG:29902 - doesn't work.

Comment: please double check what the projection of the layer is set to. I imported your example data and got them in the middle of Poetadown as Leigh got above.

Comment: I've imported as EPSG:4326 and then tried setting the project projection to EPSG:29902, EPSG:29903 and EPSG:2157 to see and all are ending up over by Madagascar

Comment: Points near Madagascar that should be in Ireland mean you got the lat-long X-Y round the wrong way. X is Longitude, Y is Latitude.

Answer (score 0):

Latitude,Longitude,Elevation

54.426758,-6.4405994,1.738

54.42676,-6.440602,1.769

54.426765,-6.4406033,1.78

54.42677,-6.4406047,1.821

Layer >> Add Layer >> Add Delimited Text Layer...

[image]

Export >> Save Features As...

[image]

Drag-n-Drop that Shapefile into a new blank canvas

[image]

The only way I can reproduce your results is to Add Layer >> Add Delimited Text Layer and set Geometry CRS to 29902. (Instead of Lat/Long 4326)

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work, I'm starting to think there's something wrong with my CSV file

Comment: What doesn't work? Please describe exact steps and what you're getting or not getting. Screen shots added to your question would help to see what you see.